# Unix file making with one randomly chosen file in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, file, unix

I’m having a hard time figuring out why my script will make files, but not add the text into the files it creates in the “eggs” directory. Can anyone help me figure out what I have wrong in my code? Or offer suggestions?
I’ve tried single > and double >> for the text appending to the file but it doesn’t. It just leaves the files blank.

Edit:

```
file=0

RandomEgg=$(( RANDOM % 10 ))
cd eggs

while [ $file -lt 10 ]
do
    touch "egg$file"
    file=$(( file +1 ))
done

for files in $(ls eggs)
do
    if [ $file -eq $RandomEgg ]
then
    echo 'Found it!' > egg$file
else
    echo 'Not Here!' > egg$file
    fi
done
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: After you do `cd eggs`, `$(ls eggs)` won't work to list the files in the directory. That looks for a subdirector of `eggs` named `eggs`.

Comment: Your second loop is `for files in ...` but then you compare `$file`. That's the variable from the first loop.

Comment: Use `for file in egg*` instead of `for file in $(ls eggs)`

Comment: Hey there, I appreciate the input! I am new to this, so I'm still learning. I have it naming the files egg0-egg09 which is why i have it written that way.

Comment: I am going to try your suggestions though. Thanks!

Comment: `$file` is `10` after the end of the first loop. So `egg$file` is `egg10` every time through the second loop. But that file doesn't exist, because you created files `egg0` through `egg9`.

Comment: Why don't you ever use the variable `$files`?

Answer (score 0):

Change the second loop to:

```
for files in egg*
do
    if [ $files = "egg$RandomEgg" ]
    then
        echo 'Found it!' > $files
    else
        echo 'Not Here!' > $files
    fi
done
```

You don't need to use `ls` to list the files, just use a wildcard. You were also listing the wrong directory -- the files were created in the current directory, not the `eggs` subdirectory.

You need to use `$files` as the filename, not `egg$file`, since that's the variable from this `for` loop.

You must use `=` to compare strings, not `-eq`. `-eq` is for numbers.

Comment: If I do this:num=0

RandomEgg=$(( $RANDOM % 10 ))

cd eggs

while [ $num -lt 10 ]
do
    touch "egg$num"
    num=$(( num +1 ))
done

for files in egg*
do
   if [ $files -eq "egg"$RandomEgg ]
then
    echo 'Found it!' >> $files
else
    echo 'Not Here!' >> $files
   fi
done

Comment: then it puts "not here!" into all the files it makes which are named "egg0 - egg9". So, it thinks the number is always 10? I'm not sure why that is if it's supposed to be a randomly chosen number.

Comment: You have to use `=` for comparing strings, not `-eq`.

Answer (score 0):

In  bash, the script could be reduced into

```
cd eggs || exit
RandomEgg=$(( RANDOM % 10 ))
for ((i = 0; i < 10; ++i)); do
    if ((i == RandomEgg)); then
        echo 'Found it!'
    else
        echo 'Not Here!'
    fi > egg$i
done
```

or,

```
cd eggs || exit
RandomEgg=$(( RANDOM % 10 ))
msg=('Not Here!' 'Found it!')
for ((i = 0; i < 10; ++i)); do echo "${msg[i == RandomEgg]}" > egg$i; done
```

Comment: This is very helpful! I appreciate the input. Can you tell me why "fi > egg$1" works? I thought that fi was just like a end of a chunk of code. I didn't realize that you could redirect the strings inside the loop like that.

Comment: @Eroscameron In bash parlance, `if ... fi` is a compound command. Any redirections  associated with a compound command apply to all commands within that compound command unless explicitly overridden. So `> egg$i` in `if ... fi > egg$i` applies to both `echo`s within the `if` construct.